# PHP Integer Problem

Tags: php

When I print this number in php **137582392964679** I get this as the output **1.37582392965E+14**

All I am doing is a simple

```
print 137582392964679;
```

Anyone know why it's doing this? It's as if it's converting to an exponential number automatically. Someone said it's because I'm on a 32 bit machine. If that's the case how can I get around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check the const PHP_INT_MAX.  You're likely over the max, which is typically around 2 billion for a 32bit system.

Comment: you can check out the math extensions here, it may help you if you're trying to do calculations with these numbers, rather than just printing. http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number you can store in a signed integer on a 32-bit machine is 2147483647. You can store numbers larger than this in a float but you risk losing some precision.

> If that's the case how can I get around this problem?

You probably want to use a big number library. Try [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php):

```
$sum = gmp_add("123456789012345", "76543210987655");
echo gmp_strval($sum) . "\n";
```

Result:

```
200000000000000
```

Another alternative you could use is [BC Math](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php).

If you don't need to do any calculations with these numbers, but just store tham correctly, then store them as strings rather than integers.

Answer (score 1):

I am on a 64 bit machine and it does the same thing. You might want to try using: `print number_format(137582392964679);`

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit build of PHP?

Answer (score 1):

That number is too big to fit into a 32-bit integer, so yes, it is converting to a floating point type automatically.  How to get around it depends on the requirements of your system.  If you aren't going to do any arithmetic then just store it as a string.  If precision isn't overly important then you could leave it as a float and format it using printf.  If precision is important and you can upgrade to 64-bit that should fix it, if you can't upgrade and you need an integer then you could look into using the BC Math PHP extension.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) clearly says:

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the
>   bounds of the integer  type, it will
>   be interpreted as a float instead.

Also your number cannot be represented accurately because of inherent floating point limitations, hence it is being approximated.