# 1.0000241703257e+14 how to convert it in PHP, it was supposed to be: 100002417032566

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Integer Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503510/php-integer-problem)

1.0000241703257e+14 how to convert it in PHP, it was supposed to be: 100002417032566

I get this value with e+14, how do I do to make PHP translate "1.0000241703257e+14" to "100002417032566"
and also in Javascript.

specially the last part.

thanks!

Comment: Where did the number come from originally?  You've lost precision in your number, and it's impossible for PHP to gain precision - the only way to do that is to store it with a higher precision in the first place.

Comment: For Javascript: http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hit the limit of PHP's integer range (which is commonly 32 bits signed). When this happens, PHP uses floating point types to represent numbers and floating point types do not have perfect precision, you get this type of result (the number is off by 4 in your case).

**There is nothing you can directly do about this.**

Your options are:

1. Do not work with these values as numbers at all, but only as strings (which is not practical most of the time).
2. Use a big integer library such as [BCMath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php).
3. Carefully rewrite critical parts of your code to make it work without going into bigint usage.

Of course it goes without saying that in the last scenario you 'd need to be pretty specific about what your requirements are. How big can these numbers be? What operations will you be performing on them?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for answering, I don't want to do math operations with it, I just want it as a string, just do the conversion to the actual values like I put on my question and thats it, just plain string with the correct value would work just fine, how could I do that? thanks!

Comment: @Grego: Where do you get that number from? You need to fix the problem right there, after you 've read it it's already too late.

Comment: I get a string from a http request. its a string JSON.

Comment: @Grego: Please edit the question and post the string you get.

Comment: the string is the number I posted. its just the value with e+14  as a string.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use number_format()

Comment: this function is turning: 100002417032570 instead of  100002417032566 how do I fix this?

Comment: @Grego: Precision **has been** lost. After it was a float, you don't get an exact printout.

Answer (score 1):

If you are beyond, PHP's max integer limit, you might have to use a big integer library such as [this one](http://pecl.php.net/package/big_int). If the actual number is not important to you (for instance if it's a Facebook user ID, etc.), just read it as a string instead of int.

Comment: I'm reading it like a string, I tried to use like this: 
$str = "1.0000241703257e+14";
echo number_format($str,0,'','');
but its making "100002417032570" instead of "100002417032566". How would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Obviously 1.0000241703257e+14 is different from 100002417032566. Where do you get the number from? If it's from some JSON parser for instance, you might have to either hack into the parser (and force it to read numbers as strings), or add quotes around the big numbers, then parse them.